# PHP echoing wrong response to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json, wampserver

Everything was working fine on UBUNTU machine, but today stoped working in my laptop Windos10 with WAMPSERVER.

I have a javscript function to show error messages received as JSON from PHP program.

PHP echo (very simple piece of code):

```
    echo '{"message":"Favor informar os campos obrigatórios." ,"field": '.json_encode($errors, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE).'}';
    return false;
```

or

```
    echo '{"message":"Senha deve ter 6 ou mais caracteres.","field":{"senha":"<6"}}'; 
    return false;
```

Java script my messagefunction (very simple piece of code):

```
function myShowMessage(resposta){
    alert(resposta);
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(resposta); <= ERROR "Json.PARSE: unexpected character  at line 1"
```

I´m expecting a mesage to show, but insted I receive something like this as a response:

```
> <br /> <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-strict-standards'
> dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'> <tr><th
> align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span
> style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size:
> x-large;'>( ! )</span> Strict standards:
> Foundationphp\Sessions\MysqlSessionHandler and
> Foundationphp\Sessions\PersistentProperties define the same property
> ($table_sess) in the composition of
> Foundationphp\Sessions\PersistentSessionHandler. This might be
> incompatible, to improve maintainability consider using accessor
> methods in traits instead. Class was composed in
> C:\wamp64\www\conexamed\conexamed\Foundationphp\Sessions\PersistentSessionHandler.php
> on line <i>65</i></th></tr> <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e'
> colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr> <tr><th align='center'
> bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left'
> bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left'
> bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left'
```

Regards

Comment: What you're getting is a PHP warning. Foundationphp\Sessions\MysqlSessionHandler and Foundationphp\Sessions\PersistentProperties define the same property ($table_sess) in the composition of Foundationphp\Sessions\PersistentSessionHandler. Fix that, and you shouldn't have problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read the error message. You'll need to fix the problem or hide strict errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
```

This needs to be called once, usually in the bootstrap/initialization script. If that doesn't help make sure there aren't any other calls to `error_reporting()` which would override your setting.

An alternative is to [modify `php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting):

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

(Again, this might get overriden at runtime by a call to `error_reporting()`).

Comment: Thank you. I´ll do this modification to try again. I am a old guy trying to learn web programming alone. I´m very geatful for the community help :)